# How do I preserve logical groupings while sorting in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sorting

I have two tables which are related in a parent-child relationship

```
Sale
sale_id | customer_name

SaleItem
item_id | sale_id | item_type
```

Each Sale record has one or more corresponding SaleItem records. My goal is to create a list of Sales with their corresponding SaleItems shown as children. I can do this with this query:

```
SELECT s.sale_id, s.customer_name, si.item_id, si.item_type 
FROM Sale s, SaleItem si
WHERE s.sale_id=si.sale_id
ORDER BY s.sale_id, si.item_id
```

which yields something like this (blank rows are added for clarity of the problem):

```
sale_id | customer_name | item_id | item_type
1       | Sam           | 1       | D
1       | Sam           | 2       | B
1       | Sam           | 3       | D

2       | Nate          | 4       | A
2       | Nate          | 5       | B

3       | Mike          | 6       | B
3       | Mike          | 7       | C

4       | Nate          | 8       | C
4       | Nate          | 9       | D
```

The ORDER BY clause results in a logical grouping of Sales with their ordered SaleItems. This provides me with the data I need to be able to code up a nice collapsible UI to represent the data:

```
-Sale 1 - Sam
 -B 
 -B 
 -D 
+Sale 2 - Nate
+Sale 3 - Mike
-Sale 4 - Nate
 -C
 -D
```

This is all fine and good but what happens when I want to sort this list by item_type? I want to end up with a result set like this (blank rows are added for clarity of the problem):

```
sale_id | customer_name | item_id | item_type
2       | Nate          | 4       | A
2       | Nate          | 5       | B

3       | Mike          | 6       | B
3       | Mike          | 7       | C

4       | Nate          | 8       | C
4       | Nate          | 9       | D

1       | Sam           | 1       | D
1       | Sam           | 2       | B
1       | Sam           | 3       | D
```

Please notice that each Sale and its corresponding SaleItems remain together. Basically what I need to do here is treat each set of Sale+SaleItems as a single element and intelligently sort them by any of the columns. Since we are essentially just sorting the Sales here and item_type applies to the SaleItem we just sort by the first SaleItem's item_type and maintain the original sorted order of the SaleItems within the Sale. I really hope that makes sense.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I going about this the wrong way? Since each Sale record is the "parent" of one or more SaleItem records the JOIN seems like overkill because I end up with the "parent" data being duplicated in each "child" row.
2. How can I sort this data by the first item_type for each Sale and still keep each Sale's SaleItems together?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: It seems you like to change the Order clause with ORDER BY item_type

Comment: `ORDER BY sale_id, item_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.sale_id, 
       s.customer_name, 
       si.item_id, 
       si.item_type,
       min(si.item_type) OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id) as min_item_type
FROM Sale s, SaleItem si
WHERE s.sale_id=si.sale_id
ORDER BY min_item_type, s.sale_id, si.item_id
```

It will give you the result close to what you showed as an example.

You can replace `min(si.item_type)` with any window function (like, `max`, `first`, `last` ...) to get the `item_type`, that will "describe" every `sale_id` group.

Comment: That works great in PostgreSQL 8.4+ but unfortunately I am stuck using 8.3. Do you have any suggestions to achieve the same thing without using window functions?

Comment: @NateThatcher The only thing I can think of is to `GROUP BY sale_id` in a subquery and joni this subquery to the main query. Not the most efficient and clear solution, but it will work.